# Convert pixel coordinates to cartesian coordinates

Tags: c++, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, cartesian-coordinates

How to convert pixel/screen coordinates to cartesian coordinates(x,y)?

The info I have on the pictures is (see image):

`vFov` in degrees, `hFov` in degrees, pixel width, pixel height

Basically what I want is to take any pixel on the image, and calculate the relative degrees it is away from the center of the image.

[image]

Comment: You picture is still very unclear and still contains _"in degrees"_. Did _you_ try anything?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can never - by principal - convert pixel coordinates to 3d-cooridnates since there is not enough information. 
This has nothing to do with c++ or any language. 
Just think of a picture you take with a camera. It is 2D, however the real word is 3D and the third dimension is not in contained in the picture (except for blurryness).

Comment: However if you had two images from a different position you could with some work and some uncertainty measure the 3d position of the object.

Comment: hmm, yeah.
It make sense. I think i have to do a different approach and use 2d instead. Do you know how to do that? :) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The think that i am trying on is to make a camera image stitcher 360.
And i need to know the exact location on the pixel in the image that is taken so i can place it in the right spot on the sphere. My ide is to have a image. Take the center of the image and calculate the degrees it is a way from center and apply it as a rotation on the camera coords to get the exact pixel position on the sphere. Sorry it is hard for me to explain. End goal is to place the image on the correct position on a equirectangular image

Comment: stitching an image is a different task. 
For stitching you need to find the matching regions in overalpping area of the original images (which can be done by cross-correlation using a fourier transform). Further you need to do some distortion correction for each camera frame and to map the result to the sphere (by some projection method, like eg. mercator projection)

There also exist libs that can do those tasks for you, like opencv
-

Comment: No it isn't a different task. This is one part of the process. I know the exact location of the image(in degrees). And i need to find what position the pixels is in responding to the image center (in degrees). Then i think i can figure out the rest. 
Don't want to use the opencv auto stitcher. It is slow and don't work in dark images.
And that is for pictures taken in random direction. It is cool but not what i need. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x - w/2
h/2 - y
```

where w and h are screen's dimensions.
Eh?