# How do I convert pixel/screen coordinates to cartesian coordinates?

Tags: image-processing, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, cartesian-coordinates

How do I convert pixel/screen coordinates to cartesian coordinates(x,y)?

The info I have on the pictures is (see image below):

`vFov` in degrees, `hFov` in degrees, pixel width, pixel height

Basically what I want is to take any pixel on the image, and calculate the pixel position from image center in degrees.

[image]

Comment: Reposting won't change the reasons why the old version(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835316/convert-pixel-coordinates-to-cartesian-coordinates) was closed. And your grammatics and spelling changes didn't improve the clarity of this question.

Comment: @QuantumDeveloper No way to make it more clear.
I edited the last question to this, but it never got reopened and I couldn't delete the question. And it did say that i could post a new question.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with "relative degree away from the center".

Comment: @QuantumDeveloper Sorry, I dont understand whats unclear with that. Calculate pixel position from center in degrees. See image. The pink dot is a pixel position.

Comment: "Calculate pixel position from center in degrees." That is much clearer.

Comment: Thanks @QuantumDeveloper,
updated the question

Answer (score 1):

For my answer I assume that your image represents a projection onto a planar surface.

Then a virtual camera can be constructed such that it sees the width/height of the image in exactly the right field of view. To get the distance `d` between the image and the camera(in pixels) a constructed right triangle can be used:

`tan(FOV/2) = width/2 / d` → `d = width/(2tan(FOV/2))`

The same equation should hold for the height.

In a similar way the angle of the pixel can be calculated(assuming the center of the image is `(0, 0)`):

`tan(angleX) = x/d` → `angleX = arctan(x/d) = arctan(x/width * 2tan(hFov))`
`tan(angleY) = y/d` → `angleY = arctan(y/d) = arctan(y/width * 2tan(vFov))`

In case the image is warped the d's of the vertical and the horizontal can be different and therefor you should not precalculate `d`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i think i am doing something wrong. Isn't this supposed to become 0,0;
`int Xpx = 1280 / 2, Ypx = 720 / 2;
       float anglex, angleY;
       float WidthPx = 1280, HeightPx = 720;
       float hFov = DegreesToRadians(45), vFov = DegreesToRadians(45);

       anglex = atan(Xpx / WidthPx * 2 * tan(hFov));
       angleY = atan(Ypx / HeightPx * 2 * tan(vFov));
       cout << RadiansToDegrees(anglex) << "\n";
       cout << RadiansToDegrees(angleY) << "\n\n";`

Comment: Not it isn't supposed to become 0. I assume that 0,0 is the center of the image, so yoiu have to offset your coordinates by width/2 and height/2:
`Xpx -= width/2; Xpy -= height/2;`

Comment: Thanks agen :D
But now if x is 1280 and width is 1280. The returning degree is 45. But i think i did see what i did wrong. `anglex = (Xpx - WidthPx / 2) / WidthPx * hFov;` This returns 22,5